# Permutations and Combinations - "Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics"

Tags: combinatorics

was studying the book "Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics" and I came across the following question from Chapter 1 that I can not solve. I would if possible give an explanation and or a solution to such an issue.

**Question:** *(Chapter 1. Permutations and Combinations, p. 23, exercise 1, question 27)*
Let $S = \{1, 2, . . . , n + 1\}$ where $n\geq 2$, and let $T=\{(x,y,Z)\in S^3; x< z \mbox{ and } y<z\}$. Show by counting $|T|$ in two different ways that
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=|T|= \begin{pmatrix}n+1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+ 2\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Thank you very much.

Kind regards.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113187/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-1n-k2-binomn13-binomn23/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof technique the book is trying to lead you to use is called [Proof by double counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)).  The idea being, if you have a scenario you wish to count and via different methods you arrive at two different expressions which correctly count the scenario, then the expressions must in fact be equal.

**Hints:**

Left side:

Break into cases based on the value of $z$.  If $z=k$, how many choices are available for $x$?  How many choices are available for $y$?

---

Right side:

Break into cases based on which of $x<y<z$ or $y<x<z$ or $x=y<z$ is true.  Pick the two or three values seen simultaneously.