# interpretation on $1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2=\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom{n+1}{3}$ and $1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3=\binom{n+1}{2}+6\binom{n+1}{3}+6\binom{n+1}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

How to interpret the results
$$
1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2=\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom{n+1}{3}
\\
1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3=\binom{n+1}{2}+6\binom{n+1}{3}+6\binom{n+1}{4}
$$

I want to find a clear argument (combinatorial example,etc.) to prove this, other than induction or merely use the formula.

Comment: What have you tried? And please add the MathJax to the title.

Comment: (The general-case formula involves Stirling numbers.)

Comment: I think this should have been posted as two separate questions. They are probably both duplicates but of different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of cubes formula can also be derived by slightly generalizing [this answer by Mike Earnest](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3113228/546005) for the sum of squares case.

Consider counting ordered quadruplets of integers $(w,x,y,z)$ s.t.

- $0 \le w, x, y < z$
- $1 \le z \le n$

When $z=k$ the number of ways to choose $(w,x,y)\in \{0, 1, \dots, k-1\}^3$ is $k^3$, so the total is $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$.

OTOH all such quadruplets can be classified as follows:

- $w, x, y$ all distinct: For a particular ordering, say $w < x < y < z$, we have ${n+1 \choose 4}$ choices.  There are $3!=6$ orderings among the $\{w,x,y\}$, so this case gives $6 \times {n+1 \choose 4}$.
- $w = x = y$: Then we're simply choosing two numbers, $w$ and $z$.  So this case gives ${n+1 \choose 2}$.
- Exactly two of the three $\{w, x, y\}$ are equal: There are $3$ ways to choose the equal pair, then $2$ ways to decide if the remaining value is bigger or smaller.  Once we decided that, say $x < w = y$, we are simply picking three numbers $x, w, z$.  So this case gives $3 \times 2 \times {n+1 \choose 3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Two different combinatorial interpretations of your first identity are given in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113187/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-1n-k2-binomn13-binomn23). My answer (not the accepted one) was based on counting the number of ways you can place two white bishops on an $n\times n$ chessboard so that they guard each other. Calling this number $B_n$, and counting in two different ways, I showed that
$$B_n=2\binom{n+1}3+2\binom n3$$
and
$$B_n=2[1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2].$$
For details see [my answer to that old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113187/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-1n-k2-binomn13-binomn23/3113294#3113294).