# Number of ways two knights can be placed such that they don't attack each other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What are the number of ways two knights can be placed on a k×k chessboard so that they do not attack each other?

```
For k from 1 to 8, the answer is given below.
0
6
28
96
252
550
1056
1848
```

I know the answer to this problem as well as the method which I found from
[Number of ways two knights can be placed such that they don't attack.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266257/number-of-ways-two-knights-can-be-placed-such-that-they-dont-attack)

[image]

But, I tried it using a different method and wanted to know the problem with my method.
Here is what I did

The Dark Blue Squares in the middle (k-4)x(k-4) chess boards, if we select the first knight in this square, then we can select the other knight so that they don't attack each other in
$(k^2-8)$ ways. So, in total $(k-4)^2.(k^2-8)$

Now, the light blue squares (the squared in the border region), there are $4.(k-4)$ such squares, and if we select our first knight from here, then the second knight can be selected in $(k^2-4)$ ways. So, in total $4.(k-4).(k^2-4)$.

Now, the white squares, there are $4.(k-4)$ such squares, and if we select our first knight from here, then the second knight can be selected in $(k^2-6)$ ways. So, in total $4.(k-4).(k^2-6)$.

Now, the red squares (corner ones), there are $4$ such squares, and if we select our first knight from here, then the second knight can be selected in $(k^2-2)$ ways. So, in total $4.(k^2-2)$.

Now, for the squares adjacent to the corner (yellow ones), there are $8$ such squares, and if we select our first knight from here, then the second knight can be selected in $(k^2-3)$ ways. So, in total $8.(k^2-3)$.

Now, at last for the square diagonally adjacent to the corner square (green ones), there are $4$ such squares, and if we select our first knight from here, then the second knight can be selected in $(k^2-4)$ ways. So, in total $4.(k^2-4)$.

Using this process we will double count our square exactly one, so our final answer will be half of this.

So, in total the number of ways is $\frac{(k-4)^2.(k^2-8)+4.(k-4).(k^2-4)+4.(k-4).(k^2-6)+4.(k^2-2)+8.(k^2-3)+4.(k^2-4)}{2}$.

But, this gives the wrong answers, like for k=8, it gives 1880, but it should give 1848, and so on. I think there might be triple counting somewhere, but I don't understand how this could be the case as my first square is selected from different zones.

Edit: I found the mistake in my method, it was a silly error, When I am excluding the positions where I can't place my knights, I didn't exclude the position where I already place the knight. So, say for the middle dark blue zone the total ways is $(k-4)^2.(k^2-9)$ and not $(k-4)^2.(k^2-8)$. And so on for others, using this I found my answer to match the correct answer.

Comment: If instead you count (using the same technique) the positions where the knights attack each other you will obtain the correct answer.