# How many ways we can place knights on a $m \times n$ chessboard in such a way that each piece does not attack the others $($modulo $10^9 + 9)$

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

How many ways we can place knights on a $m \times n$ chessboard in such a way that each piece does not attack the others $($modulo $10^9 + 9) \ ?\ (m \le 4, n \le 10^9)$

For example:

$m = 2, n = 2, ans = 16$

**Edit:**

I try to place $0,1,2,..,m \times n$ knights on chessboard then find the number of ways such that the knights do not attack each others and sum all it up.

Anwser $=$ number of ways to place knights on board $-$ number of ways to place knights on board such that the knights **do** attack each others.

This is my fomular: $2^{m \times n} - [(n - 1) \times (m - 2) + (n - 2) \times (m - 1)] \times 2 ^ {m \times n - 2}$
but it is wrong.

$2^{m \times n} $ denotes for sum of number of ways to place $0,1,..,m \times n$ knights on board:

$2^{m \times n} = \binom{m \times n}{0} + \binom{m \times n}{1} + ... + \binom{m \times n}{m \times n}$, the same for $2^{m \times n - 2}$

Since a pair of mutually attacking knights determines a $2 \times 3$ or $3 \times 2$ rectangle. There are $(n - 1) \times (m - 2) + (n - 2) \times (m - 1)$ such rectangles on the board. I got it from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2542225/785008).

If i have $k$ knights placing on the board, then $(n - 1) \times (m - 2) + (n - 2) \times (m - 1) \times \binom{m \times n - 2}{k - 2}$ is number of ways the knights **do** attack each others. But it is not true, so many cases it is duplicate. I stuck there.

I need sum all it up to number of ways to place knights on board such that the knights **do** attack each others, so I have:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m \times n}  [(n - 1) \times (m - 2) + (n - 2) \times (m - 1)] \times \binom{m \times n - 2}{k - 2}$$

is equal to:

$$[(n - 1) \times (m - 2) + (n - 2) \times (m - 1)] \times 2 ^ {m \times n - 2}$$

That is my step to find fomular.
Sory for my bad English.

Comment: First, “modulo $10^9+7$”, i.e. modulo a big prime, implies that this is a question from programming. Second, even if you asked this question on SE, it would also be closed soon since there're no efforts of you shown at all. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Sorry, Im new to SE and I forgot to mention my effort, i will update it now.

Comment: $10^9+7$ or another number like that occurs frequently in some programing contests (codechef, project Euler,...). Are you sure it is not against the rules of the contest to ask for help like this? If the contest is currently running, then the rules are strict.

Comment: I have just edited my question. It is $10^9 + 9$. The question is my programing exercise. It is so hard for me to solve.

Comment: What does it mesan to say that one knight does not attack another modulo $10^9+9$??

Comment: @bof, it's "How many ways ... modulo $10^9+9$?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's from an ongoing coding challenge.

Comment: It means the answer must be modulo by $10^9 + 9$

Comment: @Gerry_Myerson can u give me link to that challenge?